# Send parameters in request body instead in query string

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a problem with this method:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '/SalesOfferInvoiceDeliveryNote/InsertUpdateCAORAC/?cTa=b&cHTML=' + cHTML,  
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).parents('form').serialize()
//other part of method not shown, it's not relevant
```

On the server side method's signature looks like this:

```
 public string InsertUpdateCAORAC(FormCollection form = null, string cTa = "", string cHTML = null)
```

My problem is that cHTML (which represents HTML of dynamically created form for printing) becomes quickly too large to be sended through query string. I would like this parameter to be sended inside request body. What I've already tried:

```
     $.ajax({
          url: '/SalesOfferInvoiceDeliveryNote/InsertUpdateCAORAC/',  
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
          form: $(this).parents('form').serialize(), 
          cTa: 'b',
          cHTML: cHTML
          }
```

In this case, parameters cTa and cHTML are sended correctly, but form element loses all it's serialized keys. (form keys with this way of ajax calling are: form, cTa and cHTML, which is completely wrong). Is there anything I could do to send all parameters inside query string body and that form doesn't loses it's keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
form: $(this).parents('form').serialize(),
```

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) in order to create the form key/value pairs. You may take a look to [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

In order to add the additional two parameters you can use [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) like:

```
formData.append('cTa', 'b');
formData.append('cHTML', cHTML);
```

Your ajax can be:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]);
formData.append('cTa', 'b');
formData.append('cHTML', cHTML);
$.ajax({
    url: '/SalesOfferInvoiceDeliveryNote/InsertUpdateCAORAC/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData
});
```

Comment: I am receiving this error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: @FrenkyB The error is because you server side **InsertUpdateCAORAC** is wrong. You need to remove the cta and chtml parameters, because now they are part of the form and so you will get them like other form parameters. Let me know. Thanks